# How can I use the YouTube API to support HTML5 and iOS devices?

Tags: javascript, ios, actionscript-3, flash, youtube

I have been working with the demo provided at http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=youtube#chromeless_player.  What I am wondering is if there is a way to make the player HTML5 or compatible with ios devices.  I can't seem to figure out how I would do that?  I don't think the code works out of the box as I have tried it from my iphone and it doesn't seem to work...  The biggest reason I am using this is because I need to be able to adjust volume and get the video event changes...

```
<!--
You are free to copy and use this sample in accordance with the terms of the
Apache license (http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html)
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>YouTube Player API Sample</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #videoDiv { 
        margin-right: 3px;
      }
      #videoInfo {
        margin-left: 3px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("swfobject", "2.1");
    </script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      /*
       * Chromeless player has no controls.
       */

      // Update a particular HTML element with a new value
      function updateHTML(elmId, value) {
        document.getElementById(elmId).innerHTML = value;
      }

      // This function is called when an error is thrown by the player
      function onPlayerError(errorCode) {
        alert("An error occured of type:" + errorCode);
      }

      // This function is called when the player changes state
      function onPlayerStateChange(newState) {
        updateHTML("playerState", newState);
      }

      // Display information about the current state of the player
      function updatePlayerInfo() {
        // Also check that at least one function exists since when IE unloads the
        // page, it will destroy the SWF before clearing the interval.
        if(ytplayer && ytplayer.getDuration) {
          updateHTML("videoDuration", ytplayer.getDuration());
          updateHTML("videoCurrentTime", ytplayer.getCurrentTime());
          updateHTML("bytesTotal", ytplayer.getVideoBytesTotal());
          updateHTML("startBytes", ytplayer.getVideoStartBytes());
          updateHTML("bytesLoaded", ytplayer.getVideoBytesLoaded());
          updateHTML("volume", ytplayer.getVolume());
        }
      }

      // Allow the user to set the volume from 0-100
      function setVideoVolume() {
        var volume = parseInt(document.getElementById("volumeSetting").value);
        if(isNaN(volume) || volume < 0 || volume > 100) {
          alert("Please enter a valid volume between 0 and 100.");
        }
        else if(ytplayer){
          ytplayer.setVolume(volume);
        }
      }

      function playVideo() {
        if (ytplayer) {
          ytplayer.playVideo();
        }
      }

      function pauseVideo() {
        if (ytplayer) {
          ytplayer.pauseVideo();
        }
      }

      function muteVideo() {
        if(ytplayer) {
          ytplayer.mute();
        }
      }

      function unMuteVideo() {
        if(ytplayer) {
          ytplayer.unMute();
        }
      }


      // This function is automatically called by the player once it loads
      function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {
        ytplayer = document.getElementById("ytPlayer");
        // This causes the updatePlayerInfo function to be called every 250ms to
        // get fresh data from the player
        setInterval(updatePlayerInfo, 250);
        updatePlayerInfo();
        ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onPlayerStateChange");
        ytplayer.addEventListener("onError", "onPlayerError");
        //Load an initial video into the player
        ytplayer.cueVideoById("ylLzyHk54Z0");
      }

      // The "main method" of this sample. Called when someone clicks "Run".
      function loadPlayer() {
        // Lets Flash from another domain call JavaScript
        var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
        // The element id of the Flash embed
        var atts = { id: "ytPlayer" };
        // All of the magic handled by SWFObject (http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)
        swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?" +
                           "version=3&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=player1", 
                           "videoDiv", "480", "295", "9", null, null, params, atts);
      }
      function _run() {
        loadPlayer();
      }
      google.setOnLoadCallback(_run);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><div id="videoDiv">Loading...</div></td>
    <td valign="top">
      <div id="videoInfo">
        <p>Player state: <span id="playerState">--</span></p>
        <p>Current Time: <span id="videoCurrentTime">--:--</span> | Duration: <span id="videoDuration">--:--</span></p>
        <p>Bytes Total: <span id="bytesTotal">--</span> | Start Bytes: <span id="startBytes">--</span> | Bytes Loaded: <span id="bytesLoaded">--</span></p>
        <p>Controls: <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="playVideo();">Play</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="pauseVideo();">Pause</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="muteVideo();">Mute</a> | <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="unMuteVideo();">Unmute</a></p>
        <p><input id="volumeSetting" type="text" size="3" />&nbsp;<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="setVideoVolume();">&lt;- Set Volume</a> | Volume: <span id="volume">--</span></p>
      </div>
    </td></tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
​
```

Answer (score -1):

As of today (2-28-2012) there is no way to play video in-line within a browser on iOS devices. You can only proide links that will either play the video in the iOS video player, or in the youtube app. The Youtube HTML5 player does this. On HTML5 enabled devices that do not support flash, it will serve an HTML5  tag.

March 7 is some big announcement for iOS, so maybe this will change then. But I do not expect it will as this is a long-standing way of operating on iOS devices.

EDIT - Here's how to do it.

To make this work for iOS, use the new HTML5 youtube player. Instructions and code found here in the YouTube API Blog:
http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/07/new-way-to-embed-youtube-videos.html

Comment: Any ideas how to make the above code utilize the iOS app then? Right now just nothing shows up... The app would be better than nothing...

Comment: I there a JavaScript api for players like this that work on ios? Eg to play, pause, skip the video playing in the embedded player?

Comment: on IOS you click the youtube icon and it launches the video in the youtube app. Its not a brilliant implementation, but you can take that up with Google and Apple. Don't click the play button, though, because that breaks it. Ask apple why their browser can't play inline videos...