# Youtube object embed ipad

Tags: ipad, youtube

I've got a youtube video that renders ok using object embed, in all browsers except ipad, here's the code:

```
<object id="ytViewer" width="468" height="327" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3&enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=ytViewer" state="0" mute="0">
<param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always">
<param name="autoplay" value="0">
<param name="WMode" value="Opaque">
</object>
```

I'm using object embed, as I've made some custom player controls in javascript, which don't work when I use an iframe to embed the video.

It uses some javascript to pull the video in, but is it because ipad does'nt support flash embed?

Update:

```
function loadPlayer( divToLoad, plId, vidid) {

        var params = {
            allowScriptAccess: "always",
            autoplay: 0
        };
        var atts = {
            id: plId
        };
        // All of the magic handled by SWFObject (http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)
        swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?" + "&enablejsapi=1&version=3&playerapiid=" + plId, divToLoad, "468", "327", "9", null, null, params, atts);
        swfobject.createCSS("#" + plId, "display:block");

        $('#' + plId + '_container').attr('videoid', vidid);
    }
```

So I need to get the function above to add the embed tag, not sure how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only links to the YT flash video player (not even pointing to a video).

Why not just use the automatically generated "share" code of YouTube?
Look out for the "embed" button in the "share" section right below your video and copy the default code. You can even activate some additional options:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/KVHO-FWuMXs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This should work for all browsers.

**Edit:** 
if you need the object/param syntax, you can switch to the "old" way of embedding videos: the (currently fourth) option can be ticked to use this deprecated code:

```
<object width="560" height="315"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/KVHO-FWuMXs?version=3&amp;hl=de_DE"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/KVHO-FWuMXs?version=3&amp;hl=de_DE" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="560" height="315" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true"></embed></object>
```

Test it with this music video from Psy:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVHO-FWuMXs

Comment: I'm using object embed, as I've made some custom player controls in javascript, which don't work when I use an iframe to embed the video.

Comment: Just look at the options: you can still use the old embed code that works with an <object> tag (currently the 4th option)

Comment: what do you mean auco? you mean version= or state= ?

Comment: ok, it works with the embed tag, all I've got to work out now is how to get the swfobject script to add the embed tag, i've updated my code above to show the function I use.

Comment: iOS has no flash, so the swfobject script will not work. I think you want to use the newer iFrame method. These answers should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488201/youtube-html5-video-player-fallback-with-player-api-v2 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487687/youtube-api-to-work-with-html5-and-ios-devices